# How to $sum for then one array in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have the following document schema:-

```
{
  id : 1
  salary : 12000
  bonus : [{
             type: "joining bonus",
             amount: 3000
           }, 
           {
             type :  "1 year completion bonus",
             amount: 4000
           }
         ]
},
{
  id : 2
  salary : 13000
  bonus : [{
             type: "joining bonus",
             amount: 2000
           }, 
           {
             type :  "1 year completion bonus",
             amount: 6000
           }
         ]
}
```

How do I get the total salary ,  total bonus? $unwind will cause duplication here. So total sum will be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { total: { $add: ["$salary", { $sum: "$bonus.amount" }] } } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LbOdjZZh4cU)

Comment: Sorry If I am not able to explain it clearly. By totalSalary and totalBonus I meant total sum of salary and bonus from both the document i.e id:1 and id:2.

Comment: Then use a second stage on `{$group: {_id:null, total: {$sum: "$total"}}}`